# How to Insert data in a remote mysql database using in android which has a Spinner control

Tags: android, mysql

Please am having a "failed to insert" error sending data from my android app to a remote mysql database. It has a Spinner control. I'm calling an api on the remote server to to the insert, but it fails to insert.

Below is My `Main Activity` code

```
public class RCrimeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

private EditText nop, wh;
private Button bReport;
private Spinner ct;
// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
// JSON parser class
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://www.nigeriacrimewatch.com/ncwrcapi.php";
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_rcrime);

    nop = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nop);
    wh = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.wh);
    ct = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.ct);
    bReport = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnReport);
    bReport.setOnClickListener(this);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent homescr = new Intent(RCrimeActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(homescr);
        }
    });

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnReport:
            new AttemptReport().execute();
            // here we have used, switch case, because on login activity you may //also want to show registration button, so if the user is new ! we can go the //registration activity , other than this we could also do this without switch //case. default:
        default:
            break;
    }
}


class AttemptReport extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog *
     */

    boolean failure = false;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(RCrimeActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Reporting crime...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // here check for success tag

        int success;
        String name = nop.getText().toString();
        String address    = wh.getText().toString();
        String type = ct.getSelectedItem().toString();


        try {

            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nop", name));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("wh", address));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ct", type));

            Log.d("request!", "starting");

            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                    LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);

            // checking log for json response
            Log.d("Report attempt", json.toString());

            // success tag for json
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                Log.d("Crime Reported!", json.toString());
                Intent ii = new Intent(RCrimeActivity.this, MapActivity.class);
                finish();
                // this finish() method is used to tell android os that we are done with current //activity now! Moving to other activity
                startActivity(ii);
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            } else {

                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Once the background process is done we need to Dismiss the progress dialog asap *
     **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String message) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        if (message != null) {
            Toast.makeText(RCrimeActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
}
```

> API Code

```
<?php
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set('display_errors',TRUE);

  include_once "conn/nconn.php";


  $username=$_POST["username"]; $email=$_POST["email"]; 
  $password=$_POST["password"];         
   if (!empty($_POST)) { 
   if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['email']) ||   empty($_POST['password'])) { 
  // Create some data that will be the JSON response 
  $response["success"] = 0; $response["message"] = "One or both of the fields are empty ."; 
  //die is used to kill the page, will not let the code below to be executed. It will also //display the parameter, that is the json data which our android application will parse to be //shown to the users 
  die(json_encode($response)); 
  } 
$query = " INSERT INTO gmusers (username, email, password, created) values        ('$username','$email','$password', now())"; 
  $sql1=mysql_query($query); if (!empty($sql1)) { $response["success"] = 1; 
  $response["message"] = "Registered sucessfully"; die(json_encode($response)); 
  } else{ 
  $response["success"] = 0; $response["message"] = "Failed to register";
   die(json_encode($response));
   }
    } else{ 
    $response["success"] = 0; $response["message"] = " One or both of the fields are empty "; 
    die(json_encode($response));
    }

?>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you please add some relevant bits of your log too?

Comment: What error you are getting in logcat. Also try to get message from exception. add this line in catch  `Log.e("Exception",""+e.getMessage());`

Comment: I'll try that. Thanks